# getting stack overflow while creating byte array in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I created a VC++ console application (HelloWorld). In that I created one byte array with size 1316779. It's working fine when building the application. Anyway debugging the application it's giving

> Unhandled exception at 0x00969167 in HelloWorld.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow.

But when I changed size to 1010000 then it worked fine.

**My requirement is to create a byte array size of 1316779. i.e. byte myArray[1316779];**

I am working under XP operating system with Pentium processor and having 2GB RAM.

Comment: Why don't you use a vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the local array as having static storage duration

```
static byte myArray[1316779];
```

Otherwise use standard class `std::vector`

Answer (score 4):

*1316779 bytes = 1.31 MB*

MSVC puts by default a [**1 MB stack limit**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks.aspx)

> /F - Without this option the stack size defaults to 1 MB.

You either need to increase that limit or reduce your stack size (e.g. use a heap allocation). I wouldn't rely on 1010000 as well (1.01).

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, 1316779 bytes are bigger than the stack and you're blowwing it up.  So make the 1316779 bytes on the heap and pass a handle to that on the stack:

```
std::vector<byte> myHugeAmountofBytes;
myHugeAmountofBytes.reserve(1316779);
// put elemnts into myHugeAmountofBytes
```

`myHugeAmountofBytes` can now be passed via the stack with no overflow.